# Defining a probability density function in R (software), and sampling from it

Tags: probability-distributions, math-software

I'm asked to generate a random sample from a logistic distribution with the PDF,
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$$
without using the function

```
rlogis(...)
```

So I get that I need to define the function first:

```
f <- function(x){
    exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2
    }
```

I don't exactly know how to define an RNG, however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to get it by a transformation from random numbers with a uniform
distribution over $[0,1]$. Let $G$ be the (CDF) cumulative distribution function of the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ and $F$ the CDF of the logistic with
PDF $f(x)=e^{-x}/(1+e^{-x})^2$. Then  for a value $p$ with $0<p<1$ we have, since $G(p)=p$ here, that
$$ G(p)= F(u)$$
where $u$ is the point where $F(u)=p$.

Inverting $F$ gives:
$$ u= F^{-1}(p)$$
If you transform the independent random numbers $p_1,\ldots, p_n$ with uniform distribution into $F^{-1}(p_1),\ldots,F^{-1}(p_n)$, these will have the logistic distribution (can be shown by calculating the CDF). 
So what remains for you to do is to find the inverse function of $F(u)$.

This method works -- in general -- for CDF's with a continuous PDF.

Comment: Just to check... I'm getting $F^{-1}(p)=\ln\dfrac{p}{1-p}$.

Comment: Why do you ask here for the form of F^{-1}? You can check it on Wikipedia :-).

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

f <- function(x) {
  exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2
}

i<-1:100

W<- array ( runif ( i, min = -5, max = 5 ), 100 )

X<- apply ( W , 1 , FUN = f )

Comment: array creates 100 random numbers, apply applies the function f to each one of these numbers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, min=-5 and max=5 is the support for the uniform distribution, right? I'm not that used to distribution-specific arguments.

Comment: yeah, random numbers from -5 to 5, i chose those as the distribution you specified takes very small values for values outside of that range, you can increase the range but that changes the result dramatically, which leads me to think that this approach is not optimal, but you could look at something similar to this approach